# Check if a VISA card is valid for online purchase

Tags: itunes

How can check if a VISA card is valid for online purchase and can be used?

Is there a website where I can do a test purchase that will be paid back to me, after it has been received to check if the card does hold any money.

I want to do this because I get an error in iTunes saying the card is not accepted, however the card works fine for purchasing things offline in a store.
I don't yet know if this is Apple's fault or my bank's fault.

Comment: Call your bank/card issuer

Comment: Are you sure you've entered all the details correctly? Number, expiry date, name as it appears on the card, security number, your address.

Comment: @DaveM I have but there are no problems on their end they say.

Comment: @CrisF I entered all fields correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a FREE solution.  Most companies charge money to act as the intermediary between banks and such.

However, if your card works in stores, then your card is fine.  I'm willing to bet that Apple's credit card processing company doesn't support your card.

My local Vodaphone cannot set up a contract using my credit card - but they can set one up using my debit card.

Comment: It should be pointed out that these sort of transactions cost these companies money, thus the reasons that a free solution, really isn't possible in the real world.  Tt costs money to accept and charge a credit card, how much it will cost, will determined by the merchant somebody uses.  There is an underline base cost that can be calculated of course because the fees Visa, Mastercard, ect are well known.